# Sorting an array in a BASH Script by columns and rows while keeping them intact

Tags: arrays, bash, sorting

I have a test file that looks like this:

```
1   1   1   1   1
9   3   4   5   5
6   7   8   9   7
3   6   8   9   1
3   4   2   1   4
6   4   4   7   7
```

Each row is supposed to represent a students grades. So the user puts in either an 'r' or a 'c' into the command line to choose to sort by rows or columns, followed by the file name. Sorting by rows would represent getting a students average and sorting my columns would represent a particular assignments average.

I am not doing anything with the choice variable yet because I need to get the array sorted first so I can take the averages and then get the median for each column and row.

So im not sure how I can choose to sort by those specific options. Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
choice="$1"
filename="$2"
c=0
if [ -e "$filename" ]
then
      while read line
      do
         myArray[$c]=$line
         c=$(expr $c + 1)
         done < "$filename"
 else
     echo "File does not exist"
fi
printf -- '%s\n' "${myArray[@]}"
FS=$'\n' sorted=($(sort -n -k 1,1<<<"${myArray[*]}"))
echo " "
printf '%s\n' "${sorted[@]}"
```

---

This is only sorting the first column though and im not sure why its even doing that. Any push in the right direction would be appreciated. Examples would help a ton, thanks!

UPDATE:
With the changes that were suggested I have this so far:

```
#!/bin/sh

IFS=$'\n';

choice="$1"

filename="$2"

if [ -e "$filename" ]

then
        while read line

        do
                myArray[$c]=$line

                c=$(expr $c + 1)

        done < "$filename"

else
        echo "File does not exist."
fi

printf -- '%s\n' "${myArray[@]}"

width=${myArray[0]// /}

width=${#width}

height=${#myArray[@]}

bar=()

for w in $(seq 0 1 $((${width}-1)))

do
        tmp=($(sort -n <<<"${myArray[*]}"))

        for h in $(seq 0 1 $((${height}-1)))

        do
                myArray[h]=${myArray[h]#* }

                bar[h]="${bar[h]} ${tmp[h]%% *}"

                bar[h]="${bar[h]# }"

        done
done

printf -- '%s\n' "${bar[*]}"
```

But now I am getting some really strange output of way more numbers than i started with and in a seemingly random order.

Answer (score 0):

actually it is sorting $line(s) which are strings. you need to initialize the column to sort correctly, so that it is an array

*UPDATE:*

the following code is really straight forward. no performance aspects are regarded. so for large datasets this will take a while to sort column wise. **your datasets have to contain lines of numbers seperated by single spaces to make this work.**

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n';

# here you can place your read line function
ar[0]="5 3 2 8"
ar[1]="1 1 1 1"
ar[2]="3 2 4 5"
printf -- '%s\n' "${ar[*]}" # print the column wise unsorted ar
echo

# sorting
width=${ar[0]// /}
width=${#width}
height=${#ar[@]}

bar=()
for w in $(seq 0 1 $((${width}-1))); do # for each column
  #sort -n <<<"${ar[*]}" # debug, see first column removal
  tmp=($(sort -n <<<"${ar[*]}")) # this just sorts lexigraphically by "first column"
                                 # rows are strings, see initial definition of ar
  #echo
  for h in $(seq 0 1 $((${height}-1))); do # update first column
    ar[h]=${ar[h]#* } # strip first column
    bar[h]="${bar[h]} ${tmp[h]%% *}" # add sorted column to new array
    bar[h]="${bar[h]# }" # trim leading space
  done
  #printf -- '%s\n' "${bar[*]}" # debug, see growing bar
  #echo "---"
done

printf -- '%s\n' "${bar[*]}" # print the column wise sorted ar
```

prints out the unsorted and sorted array

```
5 3 2 8
1 1 1 1
3 2 4 5

1 1 1 1
3 2 2 5
5 3 4 8
```

Comment: Im pretty new at this and basically pieced this together from several other examples, could you explain what you mean?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but I am trying to figure out what to change in the above code for it to accept tabs between the number. Our test file will have the numbers separated by tabs. Is there something in the sort line that would allow it to accept this?

Comment: @adoming did you just read the beginning of my post ? "**your datasets have to contain lines of numbers seperated by single spaces to make this work.**". so replace the tabulator values with single spaces in your file or adjust the code by regarding tabs. at least you need to initialize the variable `c` which is used in the line `myArray[$c]=$line` before reading the file placing some `c=0` otherwise the output won't be sorted completely. regards.